# Does X++ have keyword analog to php's self/static?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

In most languages there is some way to implicitly refer to the containing class. In PHP it's the `self` and `static` keywords. In C# it's entirely unnecessary since you can do this:

```
class Foo {
  static void A() {
    B();
  }
  static void B() {}
}
```

But in X++ it appears I have to explicitly use the class name:

```
Foo::B();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to static methods, your assumption that in [x++](/questions/tagged/x%2b%2b) the object name and two colons are needed to call the method is correct, there is no shortcut/keyword that I'm aware of.

It is however a different case for non-static methods, these can be called using the keyword `this` (for example for classes and tables) or `element` (in form code).